# <s:textfield/> label styling for single character

Tags: html, css, jsp, struts2, styling

I need to change the color of one character in this label specifically the `*`.
This will need to be changed for several sections, but not changed for many others.  Is there an inline way for me to do this?

```
<td>
  <s:textfield label="* Bank Name" name="..." size="40" />
</td>
```

Comment: Look at the `<s:textfield>` tag `requiredLabel` attribute. By default it will generate span with `*` for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to wrap the character in `<span>` tags and set the colour in CSS. I'm not familiar with struct markup, but you should be able to apply the same concept. If not, [this](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-stextfield-textbox-example/) article will be helpful to use the `<label>` and `<input>` tags to accomplish what you want.

Try this:

HTML:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <label><span class="diff-color">*</span> Bank Name</label>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
span.diff-color {
    color: red;
}
```

That will set the color of all span elements with class name "diff-color" to red.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/yru42/1/).

Comment: `color: red;` to green? ;)

Comment: Yes, green is the new red, didn't you hear?

Comment: And dog is a new cat?

Answer (score 0):

By default Struts2 uses themes (XHTML by default) to generate common HTML MarkUp for the elements.

As pointed out by @AleksandrM's comment, `requiredLabel` attribute would generate a span with the asterisk in it, that you can style with CSS.

Be sure to give an `id` to elements by yourself, or Struts will generate an unique one by himself that would be difficult to handle (form name _ elementname plus a number or something like that).

Then this

```
    <s:textfield id = "bankName" 
               name = "bankName"
              label = "Bank Name"
      requiredLabel = "true" />

    <s:textfield id = "bankAddress" 
               name = "bankAddress" 
              label = "Bank Address"
      requiredLabel = "true" />
```

will generate the following HTML:

```
    <label for="bankName"><span>*</span>Bank Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="bankName" name="bankName" />

    <label for="bankAddress"><span>*</span>Bank Address</label>
    <input type="text" id="bankAddress" name="bankAddress" />
```

that you can style easily with:

```
<style>

    /* all "*" spans */
    label > span {
        color: silver;
    }

    /* differet style for bankName's "*" span */
    label[for=bankName] > span {
        color: red;
    }

    /* differet style for bankAddress's "*" span */
    label[for=bankAddress] > span {
        color: green;
    }

</style>
```

<kbd>[Running example](http://jsfiddle.net/AndreaLigios/vt96r/1/)</kbd>