# How can I config Struts2 color of requiredLabel

Tags: html, css, jsp, struts2, struts-tags

```jsp
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
                      "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Employee List</title>

</head>
<body>
    <s:form>

         <s:select list="{'14001','14002'}" label="EmployeeID"
            cssStyle="width:150px" name="empname" requiredLabel="true" /> 

         <s:submit />

    </s:form>
</body>
```

I want to get the asterisk (*) in red color.
How can I make this happen.

Comment: Look for generated html and apply some css to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```xml
<style>
    /* all "*" spans */
    label > span {
        color: red;
    }
</style>
```

More info on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24055881/1654265).